# Trying to result one row from two (or more) different rows

Tags: php, sql, select

I'm trying to result one row from two (or more) different rows with the image name and IsOriginal = 1 based on the same barcode (or id).

Here is my table for example:

Products

```
---------------------------------------------------------------
|  id  | IsOriginal |    Name    |    Brcode    |    Image    |
---------------------------------------------------------------
|  1   |     0      |   Pasta    |  123456789   |  pasta.jpg  |
---------------------------------------------------------------
|  1   |     1      |   Pasta    |  123456789   |     NULL    |
---------------------------------------------------------------
```

I"m trying to result this:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------
|  id  | IsOriginal |    Name    |    Brcode    |    Image    |
---------------------------------------------------------------
|  1   |     1      |   Pasta    |  123456789   |  pasta.jpg  |
---------------------------------------------------------------
```

Here is my code:

```
SELECT id, IsOriginal, Name, Brcode, Image
FROM Products
WHERE IsOriginal = 1 AND Image IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Hello  PushApp CO, welcome to StackOverflow. What problem are you having with your existing query? It would produce the result that you expect for your sample data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following

```
SELECT 
    p1.id, 
    p1.IsOriginal, 
    p1.Name, 
    p1.Brcode, 
    p2.Image as Image
FROM Products p1
join Products p2
on p1.id = p2.id
where p1.IsOriginal = 1
and p2.Image is not null
```

Output:

```
id  IsOriginal  Name    Brcode        Image
----------------------------------------------
1       1      Pasta    123456789   pasta.jpg
```